# CreateFile for Pipe Client fails with Error 231 ERROR_PIPE_BUSY

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, named-pipes

I am trying to have two DLLs communicate with each other. One serving the purpose of a Pipe Server which stays active as long as the program runs, and the other as a Pipe Client which can connect and disconnect at given circumstances while the Pipe Server is active.
Consider these functions respectfully:

---

**DLL1 (Pipe server)**

```
void DLL1_Begin() // This gets called only once, when the program starts
{
    g_hPipeServer = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\MyPipe123"),
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_NOWAIT,
            1,
            4,
            4,
            NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
            NULL);

    if (g_hPipeServer == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        char error[256];
        sprintf_s(error, "Server pipe error %lu", GetLastError());
        MessageBox(NULL, error, "Fatal error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    ConnectNamedPipe(g_hPipeServer, NULL);
}

void DLL1_End() // This gets called only once, when the program closes
{
    DisconnectNamedPipe(g_hPipeServer);
    CloseHandle(g_hPipeServer);
}
```

---

**DLL2 (Pipe client)**

```
// Like DLL1, DLL2 gets initialized once and is always attached to the program.
// These functions are called occasionally and are meant solely for the Pipe.

void DLL2_InitPipeClient()
{
    g_hClientPipe = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\MyPipe123"),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (g_hClientPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // This scope is of interest
    {
        char error[256];
        sprintf_s(error, "Client pipe error %lu", GetLastError());
        MessageBox(NULL, error, "Fatal error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void DLL2_EndPipeClient()
{
    CloseHandle(g_hClientPipe);
    g_hClientPipe = NULL;
}
```

---

These are the steps:

1. Program starts, `DLL1` gets attached and `DLL1_Begin` gets called
2. At any time, user interacts with button, `DLL2` gets attached and `DLL2_InitPipeClient` gets called. `DLL2` remains attached to the program as long as it's running
3. At any time, user interacts with another button, `DLL2_EndPipeClient` gets called, then `DLL2_InitPipeClient` gets called immediately after.
4. Client pipe fails to initialize with `CreateFile` for a second time, giving `error 231`

The user needs to be able to immediately "restart" the Client pipe whenever they want. Why would the server pipe be busy? CloseHandle always returns true, but after that, calling `CreateFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` with `error 231`.

Note that I can only have one pipe client at a time. I tried setting maxinstances parameter for `CreateNamedPipe` to a higher value just in case, but the error doesn't go away and I can't initialize the Client pipe... How do I fix this?

By the way, communication works back and forth. I just can't get the the Client pipe to close and start again, and I can't have it active all the time, which is beyond me.

Comment: Everything happens in the same process? And the 2 initialization functions are called from each *.dll*'s *DllMain*?

Comment: Yes, both of the DLLs have that rule. But the `DLL2`'s initialization function can also get called at any time the user clicks a button, per se. Of course, `DLL2_EndPipeClient` gets called before opening it again.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `CloseHandle` in `DLL2_EndPipeClient`?
"If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

Comment: No, I haven't. My bad. After doing so, CloseHandle returns false with the error code 6 "Invalid handle". Which is weird because the client pipe opens fine for the first time, before closing and opening again optionally.

Comment: Why don't you check what *ConnectNamedPipe* returns? Also in the client side did you also try *WaitNamedPipe*?

Comment: Doesn't by any chance the 1st client connection work well, and only subsequent attempts fail with 231?

Comment: @CristiFati That's exactly what happens. It connects to the pipe for the first time without a problem and communications work. WaitNamedPipe just gets stuck, I've tried setting my own timeout to ensure it isnt a bug. Waited over a good minute, which is too much to wait even before it connects.

Comment: That's normal. After each client disconnects, you must also reconnect the server endpoint, in order to accept another client. That is "a bit hard" to implement with your current design. What of your current restrictions can be dropped?

Comment: @CristiFati That's what I dream of to do and get the thing running properly, but unfortunately I cannot. It's beyond me, and the client needs to be active all the time, until the program closes ofc.

Comment: You mean the server must be active all the time. That's doable, but the server must also be notified when a client disconnects. Would you like me to take a shot?

Comment: Yes, the server. Not the client, my bad. Well, I would appreciate it, thanks. I don't know whether the server needs to be notified nor how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[MS.Docs]: ConnectNamedPipe function (namedpipeapi.h) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-connectnamedpipe#remarks) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> A named pipe server process can use **ConnectNamedPipe** with a newly created pipe instance. ***It can also be used with an instance that was previously connected to another client process; in this case, the server process must first call the [DisconnectNamedPipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-disconnectnamedpipe) function to disconnect the handle from the previous client before the handle can be reconnected to a new client***. Otherwise, **ConnectNamedPipe** returns zero, and [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) returns ERROR_NO_DATA if the previous client has closed its handle or ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED if it has not closed its handle.

I modified your sources to have a working example.

*inc.h*:

```c
#pragma once

// Dumped everything here for convenience.
// In real world, each .dll would have its own header file(s).

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define PIPE_NAME "\\\\.\\pipe\\DemoPipe1234"

#if defined(_BUILD_NO_DLLS)
#  define DLL_EXPORT_API
#else
#  if defined(DLL_EXPORTS)
#    define DLL_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define DLL_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#endif

#if defined(__cpluscplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL_EXPORT_API void DLL1_Begin();
DLL_EXPORT_API void ReconnectServerEndpoint();
DLL_EXPORT_API void DLL1_End();

DLL_EXPORT_API void DLL2_InitPipeClient();
DLL_EXPORT_API void DLL2_EndPipeClient();

#if defined(__cpluscplus)
}
#endif
```

*srv.c*:

```c
#define DLL_EXPORTS
#include "inc.h"


HANDLE g_hPipeServer = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;


void DLL1_Begin()
{
    //printf("%s - 0x%016llX\n", __FUNCTION__, g_hPipeServer);
    g_hPipeServer = CreateNamedPipe(PIPE_NAME,
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_NOWAIT,
            1,
            4,
            4,
            NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
            NULL);

    if (g_hPipeServer == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Server pipe creation error %lu", GetLastError());
    }
}


void ReconnectServerEndpoint()
{
    if (g_hPipeServer == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Can't reconnect invalid pipe\n");
        return;
    }
    if (!DisconnectNamedPipe(g_hPipeServer)) {
        printf("Server pipe disconnect error %lu\n", GetLastError());
    }
    if (!ConnectNamedPipe(g_hPipeServer, NULL)) {
        DWORD gle = GetLastError();
        if (gle != ERROR_PIPE_LISTENING) {
            printf("Server pipe connect error %lu\n", gle);
        }
    }
}


void DLL1_End()
{
    //printf("%s - 0x%016llX\n", __FUNCTION__, g_hPipeServer);
    if (g_hPipeServer != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (!DisconnectNamedPipe(g_hPipeServer)) {
            printf("Server pipe disconnect error %lu\n", GetLastError());
        }
        CloseHandle(g_hPipeServer);
        g_hPipeServer = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
}
```

*cli.c*:

```c
// Like DLL1, DLL2 gets initialized once and is always attached to the program.
// These functions are called occasionally and are meant solely for the Pipe.

#define DLL_EXPORTS
#include "inc.h"


HANDLE g_hClientPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;


void DLL2_InitPipeClient()
{
    //printf("%s - 0x%016llX\n", __FUNCTION__, g_hClientPipe);
    g_hClientPipe = CreateFile(PIPE_NAME,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (g_hClientPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Client pipe creation error %lu\n", GetLastError());
    }
}


void DLL2_EndPipeClient()
{
    //printf("%s - 0x%016llX\n", __FUNCTION__, g_hClientPipe);
    if (g_hClientPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        CloseHandle(g_hClientPipe);
        g_hClientPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
}
```

*main00.c*:

```c
#include "inc.h"
#include <conio.h>

#if defined(_BUILD_NO_DLLS)
#  include "cli.c"
#  include "srv.c"
#endif


void loop()
{
    char c = 0;
    while (c != 0x1B) {
        //printf("\n************ MENU ************\nPress:\n- c to connect client\n- d to disconnect client\n- ESC to quit\n- Anything else to do nothing\n******************************\n");
        printf("\nPress: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:\n");
        c = getch();
        switch (c) {
            case 0x1B: {
                printf("Exit\n");
                break;
            }
            case 0x43:
            case 0x63: {
                printf("Connect client\n");
                DLL2_InitPipeClient();
                break;
            }
            case 0x44:
            case 0x64: {
                printf("Disonnect client\n");
                DLL2_EndPipeClient();
                ReconnectServerEndpoint();
                break;
            }
            default: printf("Do nothing\n");
        }
    Sleep(500);
    }
}


int main()
{
    DLL1_Begin();

    loop();

    DLL1_End();
    printf("\nDone.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**:

- I added *ReconnectServerEndpoint* that should be called when a client disconnects
- I linked the executable to the 2 *.dll*s. I don't know how are you supposed to do things maybe dynamically load the *.dll*s, but it shouldn't make any difference

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q074753431]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> cli.c
> inc.h
> main00.c
> srv.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL srv.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll1.dll
> srv.c
>    Creating library dll1.lib and object dll1.exp
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL cli.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll2.dll
> cli.c
>    Creating library dll2.lib and object dll2.exp
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /W0 main00.c  /link /NOLOGO /OUT:main_dll.exe dll1.lib dll2.lib
> main00.c
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> cli.c
> cli.obj
> dll1.dll
> dll1.exp
> dll1.lib
> dll2.dll
> dll2.exp
> dll2.lib
> inc.h
> main00.c
> main00.obj
> main_dll.exe
> srv.c
> srv.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> main_dll.exe
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Connect client
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Disonnect client
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Connect client
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Disonnect client
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Connect client
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Disonnect client
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Connect client
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Connect client
> Client pipe creation error 231
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Disonnect client
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Disonnect client
>
> Press: c to connect client, d to disconnect client, ESC to exit:
> Exit
>
> Done.
> ```

In the above output, it's visible that *ERROR_PIPE_BUSY* only occurs when the client tries to connect twice (there's already a connected client).

For more details, you could take a look at:

- [[MS.Learn]: Multithreaded Pipe Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/multithreaded-pipe-server)
- [[MS.Learn]: Named Pipe Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-client)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to put all of this together so perfectly! But, is there truly no way to surpass the DisconnectNamedPipe? Once DLL1 has been attached, the Pipe Server gets created and that's it. The Server Pipe's handle is what's being used as long as the program runs. How can there be more than one client connected if I've closed the handle for the Pipe Client? Is there a way I can keep track of the number of clients on the Pipe Server and properly "dispose" them or something similar, idk?

Comment: A pipe (like the name suggests), is not a server (like in (socket) server client architecture) but a communication channel with 2 endpoints (also called server and client). When the client disconnects, in order for the pipe to be reused (other client to connect to the client endpoint), the server endpoint **must reconnect**. Yes, it's possible to have multiple clients simultaneously, but each requires a separate pipe instance (you'd have to *CreateNamedPipe* for each).

Comment: @IOviSpot `DisconnectNamedPipe` ( `FSCTL_PIPE_DISCONNECT` ) is mandatory call after client was disconnected.

Comment: I'll try and see if I can get the program redesigned to accept "restarting the pipe server", in that case, and give you the bounty I submitted before time runs out.

Comment: What are the current restrictions (and why)? I was under the impression that the program is in the design phase.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get the program redesigned to close and start the "pipe server" again. The restrictions and their reason is beyond me.

Comment: Given the restrictions, I assume moving to sockets would also be forbidden :) . Or what is going on here? Because I have a feeling that the full picture is not clear.

Comment: It's simple. As soon as the program starts, DLL1 gets attached, the "pipe server" gets started and that's it. DLL2 gets attached afterwards, "pipe client" connects and remains connected before the user clicks on the action button to restart the client. The pipe server should always remain on. I cannot stop the pipe server unless I close the program. That is the full picture pretty much...

Comment: Hmm, considering latest requests, it seems designed by someone without a clear understanding of *Win*'s pipes mechanism.

Comment: The two DLL projects are not mine, and do a lot of things and cannot get their main thread's loop halted, because they do way too much work in other threads while queuing those actions in the main thread. Halting any of them would cause a lot of unpredictable effects, so I'll pass on that. I'm the designer of the DLL's communication system via pipe, and no I don't really have a clear understanding of it, especially the part that the pipe actually needs to be halted and initiated again for the client to "reconnect", before your answer explained it thoroughly to me. :)

Comment: The biggest pain in the neck is halting DLL2's main loop while DLL1's "server pipe" "is restarting" before continuing with work. I'll have to convince the original designer to use WebSockets or anything else that can do what it needs to do...

Comment: I'm sure they'll understand (considering this a dead end). It won't make any difference, but please leave a comment with the decision (when there'll be one).

Comment: Well, I'll leave an upvote and even accept your answer since you've actually solved my problem and answered the question (that I had with a different project as well, to confirm the answer). Sorry about the bounty, though.

Comment: Thank you and do not worry. I refreshed my pipe knowledge :)