# Python get/set port and identify it without communication

Tags: python, python-sockets

I am selecting a random port that all my applications can use to communicate on that changes each time.

```py
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 0))
addr = s.getsockname()
port = addr[1]
s.close()
```

Now I'm looking for a good way for other scripts to find that port without prior communication in any form (on windows) using windows commands or API calls. Something **like** registering the port in registry but without requiring administrative privileges. (not that though as explained below). A named service port would be nice but I don't think that exists in windows.

I know I can use a temp file to store it but that seems like a cheap way to do it and will require some clean-up and error checking.

Currently I am using sys.argv and opening the scripts with the args sent but there are cases where the user will open them without args so its not the best solution for me.

I have also tried using `netstat -a -o` to get all used ports then using the PIDs from that searching though `tasklist /fi pid eq #####` to get the name that matches what I'm looking for. However when developing the name is `python.exe` which can have multiple ports assigned and it also takes a long time to complete so I cannot use that either.

Comment: What do you mean by "*changes each time*"? Assuming that one process selects the port, and others just use it, writing it in registry (or in a file on disk) should work. Pipes could also be a choice.

Comment: @CristiFati when the program launches it selects a random open port. If that program crashes unexpectedly then the port will still be saved to a file or registry causing more issues. can you show an example of Pipes ?

Comment: [\[SO\]: CreateFile for Pipe Client fails with Error 231 ERROR\_PIPE\_BUSY (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74844414/4788546), but it's in *C*. You could use http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32pipe.html, but I have a feeling that using a file would be the easiest, then registry would be the next option.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks. I managed to use win32pipe and win32file to create a named pipe. I will upload a solution once i work out the few problems with it.

Comment: Feel free to update the question with the code and problems (if any) :)